# How to split and array into n arrays javascript

Tags: javascript

let's say i have an array [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] and i want to split it into n parts let's say 3 part so the result is supposed to be [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ],[ 4, 5, 6, 7],[ 8, 9, 10 ] but the code i have right now is or O(n*m) which is bad. Is there an optimal way of doing this?

```
const items = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

const n = 3
const result = [[], [], []]

const wordsPerLine = Math.ceil(items.length / 3)

for (let line = 0; line < n; line++) {
  for (let i = 0; i < wordsPerLine; i++) {
     const value = items[i + line * wordsPerLine]
      if (!value) continue //avoid adding "undefined" values
      result[line].push(value)
  }
}
```

Comment: Why are there two 4's in your result?

Comment: @Ivar i didn't even notice, that is why i posted it here so you guys can help me out

Comment: no please @Yogi i think the second answer does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To split up the array as evenly as possible:

```js
function split_array(a, nparts) {
  const quot = Math.floor(a.length / nparts)
  const rem = a.length % nparts
  var parts = []
  for (var i = 0; i < nparts; ++i) {
    const begin = i * quot + Math.min(rem, i)
    const end = begin + quot + (i < rem)
    parts.push(a.slice(begin, end))
  }
  return parts
}

var chunks = split_array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], 3)
console.log(JSON.stringify(chunks))
```

Output:

```
[[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7],[8,9,10]]
```

The size of each part will never differ by more than 1.

Comment: Splice also has O(n) complexity right? 
So is this O(n^2) ?

Comment: Overall this algorithm is O(n), since the original array is never iterated over more than once. The `for` loop is iterated over `nparts` times and each call to slice is of cost `O(n / nparts)` roughly speaking. So `nparts * O(n / nparts) = O(n)` if you can forgive my abuse of the big-Oh notation to make this point.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the result needs to be `[[ 1, 2, 3, 4 ], [ 5, 6, 7, 8 ], [ 9, 10 ]]` you could use Array.reduce:

```
const items = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ]

const parts = 3
const wordsPerLine = Math.ceil(items.length / parts)

const result = items.reduce((resultArray, item, index) => {
  const arrayIndex = Math.floor(index / wordsPerLine)
  if (!resultArray[arrayIndex]) {
    resultArray[arrayIndex] = [] // start a new array
  }
  resultArray[arrayIndex].push(item)
  return resultArray
}, [])

// result => [[ 1, 2, 3, 4 ], [ 5, 6, 7, 8 ], [ 9, 10 ]]
```

Answer (score 2):

We can write `chunk(arr, size)` using [inductive reasoning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction) -

1. If `arr.length` is less than or equal to `size`, there are no more chunks to make. Return the singleton chunk of `[ arr ]`
2. Otherwise (inductive) `arr.length` is greater than `size`, there is at least one chunk to make. Slice one chunk off the left of the array and prepend it to the result of the recursive sub-problem.

```js
function chunk(arr, size) {
  if (arr.length <= size)
    return [ arr ]                                                 // 1
  else
    return [ arr.slice(0, size), ...chunk(arr.slice(size), size) ] // 2
}

const a =
  [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ]

const size =
  Math.ceil(a.length / 3)

const result =
  chunk(a, size)

console.log(
  JSON.stringify(result)
)
```

```js
[[0,1,2,3],[4,5,6,7],[8,9]]
```

Visualize the evaluation -

```js
chunk([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], 4)
[ [0,1,2,3], ...chunk([4,5,6,7,8,9], 4) ]
[ [0,1,2,3], ...[ [4,5,6,7], ...chunk([8,9], 4) ] ]
[ [0,1,2,3], ...[ [4,5,6,7], ...[ [8,9] ] ] ]
[ [0,1,2,3], ...[ [4,5,6,7], [8,9] ] ]
[ [0,1,2,3], [4,5,6,7], [8,9] ]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use [array.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice#return_a_portion_of_an_existing_array).

As the documentation reads, given the correct parameters, it will return a subset of your array, which you can then store into a new one.

For instance:

```
let n = 3;
let i = 0;
let resultArray = [];
let startArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
let arrayPortion = [];
const wordsPerLine = Math.ceil(startArray.length / n);

do {
  arrayPortion = startArray.slice(n*i, n*(i+1));
  resultArray.push(arrayPortion);
  i++;
} while (arrayPortion.length==n && i*n<startArray.length); // Your end conditions.
```

This should work for any `n`.

Comment: what if i want to split the array into 3 parts for any size of the array and not necessarily splitting it into the number of items it should contain

Comment: Do you mean getting 3 arrays with a random amount of the initial's array values?
Like any of the following?
One invocation: [ [1,2], [3], [4,5,6,7,8,9,10] ]
Another invocation: [ []. [1,2,34,5,6,7,8], [9,10] ]

Comment: no please. don't worry someone answered it

Answer (score 0):

**With O(n)**

```
const items =  [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
  const partitionSize = Math.ceil(items.length / 3)
  const result = [[], [], []]
  let resultIndex = 0, subArrayIndex = 0;
  for (let line = 0; line < items.length; line++) {
     result[resultIndex].push(items[line])
     subArrayIndex++;
     if(subArrayIndex == partitionSize) {
     resultIndex++;
     subArrayIndex = 0;
     }
  }
```

Result:

```
 0: (7) [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
1: (7) [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
2: (6) [15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
```

Comment: this doesn't work for const items = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20] like i want to dive the array into 3 parts it doesn't work

Comment: @MoroOwusuAfriyie updated code according.. now you can pass required number of element.. just take care of null and undefine, i did't handle edge cases :)

Comment: if i change the partitionSize to Math.ceil(items.length /4 ) it fails.. All i wanted was to be able to create sub arrays given the number of partitions i want . you can take a look at the second answer and try it out.